# Read and Extract file from Azure Folder c#

Tags: c#, azure, serialization, directory, stream

I want to read XML Files from the folder that is in ZIP Format and zip folder exist in azure cloud that need user and password to get into account.
I want this code in c# ..Please help me to Read files and XML from ZIP Folder that exist in azure .

I dont know how can I read xml file from zip folder that is in azure. I wrote a Good code that Extarct folder and read xml file and save in DB but in local Directory in c#

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Below is something that you can do to achieve your requirement.

Firstly, I have tried to download the zip folder from azure blob storage and then Unzip using `ZipArchive`.

```
string connectionString = "<CONNECTION_STRING>";
string containerName = "<CONTAINER_NAME>";
string blobName = "<BLOB_NAME>";
string destinationFolder = "<LOCAL_FOLDER_PATH>";


BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream();
blobClient.DownloadTo(zipStream);
zipStream.Position = 0;

Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolder);

using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry zipArchiveEntry in zipArchive.Entries)
    {
        string dextinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, zipArchiveEntry.FullName);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(dextinationFilePath));
        zipArchiveEntry.ExtractToFile(dextinationFilePath, true);
    }
}
```

> I wrote a Good code that Extarct folder and read xml file and save in DB but in local Directory in c#

You can place the code after the above code and then you can able to read the files.

Results:

[image]

[image]